# In Xcode 4.3.3 (4E3002): Ctrl-Dragging from a button into a .h file in Storyboard causes Xcode to crash

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I have a big problem: Whenever I'm in storyboard and Ctrl-Drag from a button into its .h file, give a random name and click enter to create an action, Xcode crashes - always.
I already restarted Mac OS, reinstalled Xcode, made a new storyboard from scratch, but it all doesn't help, the error doesn't change the tiniest bit.
Has anyone any idea what is wrong with my setup?

Edit:
I solved it. The problem was: The header view for the ViewController, which contained the button, was toggled to an iOS library header (.h) file. So Xcode tried to write into a write-protected library .h file and therefore crashed.
I Ctrl-Dragged the Button into a correct in-the-project header file and it worked flawlessly.

Since I'm totally new to Xcode I didn't recognize that the file wasn't autogenerated from Xcode but prewritten and an iOS library file.